# Can you build validation into Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

My company uses an Excel data template that we send to all new customers that they must fill out and send back to us as part of implementation. The data template gets uploaded to our cloud application where the customers then interact with the data. The database that gets populated from the templates has strict parameters that often get broken or cause issues based on the data the customer enters into the templates.

Is it possible to enforce validation on the actual Excel template to prevent bad data from being uploaded which then forces our development team to have to manually run updates in production instead of just nixing the problem from the start.

Examples of the validation needed to enforce in specific columns in Excel template:

- 31 character limitation
- No special characters allowed (only dashes, underscores, and single spaces are allowed)
- 8 digit Numeric only values in certain fields
- 9 digit Numeric only values in certain fields

Comment: `Can you build validation into Excel using VBA?` Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need VBA if those are your requirements.

For the first, third and fourth bullets, using `Data -> Data Validation` menu would do (`allow -> whole number`, `allow -> text length`).

For the second bullet, you can use the custom option of data validation and create a formula for not allowing special characters.